# special string formatting within a Series in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string-formatting, series

I am looking for a customized version of the `Series.str.zfill(width)` method. This method add zeros in a string such that the string has `width` characters. I am looking for something that does this, but with any characters (or sequence of characters), not only with 0. For example adding '-' as many times as needed from the left so that the string has `width` characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`Series.str.rjust`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rjust.html) that takes `width` and `fillchar` as arguments:

> Filling left side of strings in the Series/Index with an additional
>   character.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom function like `left_fill` below and use `pandas.Series.apply` to map it over the full series.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'apple'])

def left_fill(string, char, length):
    while len(string) < length:
        string = char + string
    return string

s.apply(left_fill, args = ('-', 5))
```

But, as mentioned in the comments, you are better off using the `pandas` built-in `rjust` method versus creating your own! Mine is just another, less-performant example.

Comment: Really we shouldn't offer `apply` answers if a vectorised method exists

Comment: It's just another way of doing things -- I didn't claim mine way more performant. I see no harm in looking under the hood a bit and leaving this here.

Comment: For small datasets `apply` will be faster but the existing method should scale better, although list comprehensions are sometimes even faster, it's just that for a pandas user they should really only use `apply` if there is no other option and this is quite rare. It can also confuse users if they automatically think to solve a problem using `apply` rather than look for a vectorised method IMO, as I've seen a lot of user code like this, feel free to leave it here but this is just my view on this